# How to use lambda by having inputs?

Tags: python

I am new to python and having a problem of getting inputs from lambda. I created a function for computation:

```
def d_a():
    d_a_compute = lambda v_i, t, a: (v_i * t) + (0.5 * a) * (t ** 2)

    print("KINEMATIC EQUATIONS")
    print ("d_a = Displacement with acceleration")
    print ("v_f = Final velocity")
    print ("v_f_squared = Final velocity squared")
    print ("d = Displacement without acceleration")
    print ("t = Time")
    print ("a = Acceleration")
    print ("v_i = Initial velocity")
    print ("===================================")
    var = ["d_a", "v_f", "v_f_squared", "d", "t", "a","v_i"]
    print ("1.", var[0])
    print ("2.", var[1])
    print ("3.", var[2])
    print ("4.", var[3])
    print ("5.", var[4])
    print ("6.", var[5])
    print ("7.", var[6])
    print ("===================================")
    num = int(input("Input the number you want to compute: ")) - 1
    choice = (var[num])
    if choice == "d_a":
        float(input("Enter the initial velocity: "))
        float(input("Enter the time: "))
        float(input("Enter the acceleration: "))
```

As you can see, I did not call the function because I want to know first how to make my inputs connected to lambda in my function. I want my initial velocity to be connected to `v_i`, etc. How can I do this?

Comment: I edited my concern. I intentionally not call the function because I don't know how can I connect my inputs from the lambda.

Comment: I didn't understand your question. Why don't you just assign the three inputs to variables, and then pass those three variables as arguments to `d_a_compute`?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you **can** do this ... but you probably should not (see [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations) )

```
# def d_a(): < you dont need(or want) this line ...
d_a_compute = lambda v_i, t, a: (v_i * t) + (0.5 * a) * (t ** 2)
...
if choice == "d_a":
   result = d_a_compute( # <- you need to actually call you lambda
     float(input("Enter the initial velocity: ")), # v_i
     float(input("Enter the time: ")),  # t
     float(input("Enter the acceleration: ")) # a
   )
   print("DA = ", result)
```

as pointed out in the comments its almost certainly more readable to just use a normal function here (in fact it is explicity called out in [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations) that you should use a normal function definition rather than assign a lambda to a variable)

```
  def d_a_compute(v_i, t, a):
      return  (v_i * t) + (0.5 * a) * (t ** 2)
```

instead

Comment: I tried your updated code, I did not receive an error. But for calling the d_a, am I supposed to get the answer or not?

Comment: @TomKarzes because he specifically said he wants a lambda and has the lambda bit implemented ... please cite where you see "you should never define a function like this" ... (I mostly agree but i dont think its any kind of cardinal sin) `sqrt = lambda x:x**0.5` is something i have done before

Comment: @JoranBeasley Hey thanks! I got it now! Thank you so much! You saved me

Comment: @JoranBeasley If that's the case, then it's an x-y question and the appropriate response is to explain it as such, not encourage code that doesn't make sense.

Comment: @TomKarzes added to my edit to discourage doing this ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley I think the main motivation for `lambda` is that you can use it in a context where you don't want to associate it with a name, and just want to define it inline (i.e., in an expression context).  This most typically occurs when it is being used as an argument to a function, such as the `key` argument to a sort function (or, in Python 2, the comparison argument).

Comment: @JoranBeasley It is sometimes also used when a function returns a `lambda`, where it again has no need to associate the `lambda` with a name.